# Getting attribute inside div web scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to use cheerio to webscape a sports [website](https://www.si.com/scoreboard) . One of the things that I need is `data-gameid` from this line

```
<div class="component game scoreboard-game margin-24-bottom epl full time  margin-24-bottom" data-gameid="2146609" data-league="epl" data-show-date="" data-extra-class="margin-24-bottom" data-viewport-width="">
```

I really just can't figure out how to get the `data-gameid` number. I know its a short question but i don't know what else to say to make it more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data) method like so:

```
$(".game").data("gameid");
```

Or use [`.attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr):

```
$(".game").attr("data-gameid");
```

Or for a pure JavaScript solution:

```
document.querySelector(".game").getAttribute("data-gameid");
```

Comment: Wouldn't `".game[data-gameid]"` be better suited as your CSS selector? Then you can ensure that if you do get back an element with the `game` class, it will also have a _`gameid`_ data attribute, thereby preventing any issues where that attribute isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to get it from the DOM tree simply use the `.attr` method.

```js
const gameId = $('.game').attr('data-gameid');
```

If you're talking about extracting it from that string do the following.

```js
const nodeStr = `<div class="component game scoreboard-game margin-24-bottom epl full time  margin-24-bottom" data-gameid="2146609" data-league="epl" data-show-date="" data-extra-class="margin-24-bottom" data-viewport-width="">`;
const gameId = /data-gameid="(\d+)"/mgi.exec(nodeStr)[1]; // "2146609"
```